# Can more HTML attributes or values hurt Angular performance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, frontend

If there is `p` like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="text in texts">{{text}}</p>
```

Does adding more classes to `p` hurt Angular performance while rendering html? for example, this code:

```
<p ng-repeat="text in texts" class="normal par red small italic">{{text}}</p>
```

If it cuases performance issues, is it really notable?

Comment: Considering how much baggage Angular *itself* already is, I can't imagine the mere addition of one or two attributes possibly making it *much* worse.

Comment: I'd guess that it makes no difference, and that Angular just creates the class attribute with the string value it's given in the template.

Comment: Your question is way too general to answer this. It depends. if you have 1000 texts and use a class which uses e.g. transition you probably don't want to view it in IE. In your case, adding a normal class attribute doesn't even trigger something that lets angular work more. Using an angular directive for it like `ngClass` and relying on changeDetection, thats another story...

Comment: @Mina, Salam,chetori?

Answer (score 0):

First, one of the aspects you can tune in the `ng-repeat` is the unique key : Angular adds automatically the `$$hashKey` property to each object in your array.

You can add a `track by` to improve your loop's performance.

Then, if it's just for adding classes, it's OK. But,if you have a large list of texts and you are willing to add directives (ex: `ng-click`) on each element, then you could observe some slow rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, classes are just some strings and nothing more. Angular even doesn't need to think about it. If there is a cost, it's on browser side which should compile your classes and assign the styles.

because I can guest why you are adding classes, I think having more classes is also better than hierarchical CSS styling because it requires less DOM queries and manipulation.

It's OK. However, still benchmarking can lead you to some more sophisticated issues. So give it a try.